# Is there a Python JSON encoder which JUST works?

Tags: python, json

I understand this may be a stupid question in many contexts, but does there exist a Python JSON encoder which converts everything it does not understand (eg. float32, float64, high precision decimal, etc.) to string?

I am having a hard time iterating multiple levels deep through my data structures to convert all datatypes json, simplejson & ujson modules complain about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy to make the standard `json` module do what you want by setting the `default` parameter to a function that just calls `str()` on its argument:

```
import json

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

print json.dumps(
    {
        'simple_string': 'i encode easily',
        'simple_int': 42,
        'complex': MyObject('this is a test')
    }, default=str, indent=2)
```

This will call `string(obj)` for any `obj` that is not one of the
types the `json` module is able to encode natively.  The above example
results in:

```
{
  "simple_int": 42, 
  "simple_string": "i encode easily", 
  "complex": "this is a test"
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I feel like this should be more explicit in the documentation.

Comment: It's in the [Basic Usage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) section of the documentation: "default(obj) is a function that should return a serializable version of obj or raise TypeError. The default simply raises TypeError."

Comment: `lambda obj: str(obj)` is just `str`: `json.dumps(..., default=str, indent=2)`

Answer (score -1):

You could try [JSONPickle](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle) (I am a contributor)